# Creating an array of generics in java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have been out of touch with Java for a while and trying to create an array of generics and a bit confused.

For regular types I can do things like this:

```
 String s[] = new String[10];
```

However if I have my own data type say a bag of integers and I want to define an array of Bag why can't I do this:

```
 Bag<Integer> b[] = new Bag<Integer>[10];
```

Neither can I do this:

```
 Bag<Integer> b[] = (Bag<Integer>) new Object[10];
```

The above doesnt work, how do I fix it?

EDIT: I saw the "duplicate" answer before I posted but I am unable to figure out how to use information in that answer to solve my problem. I have boiled down my issue to the simplest form and it doesnt appear to be the same.

Comment: I get a generic array creation error.

Comment: you should give the definition of `Bag`

Comment: @davidxxx If you just need to test it, use `class Bag<T> {}`. The full definition isn't necessary.

Comment: Generics are erased at runtime, but since array want to validate type of inserted elements at runtime it doesn't want to accept generics. Instead consider using `List<Bag<Integer>>`